# Adding options to select dynamically

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic, xataface

I have pulled data from backend using Ajax/JSON, and I am trying to append this data to the select box using jQuery. Data is appended to the select box properly, but it is shown on the page only when I put `alert("some text")`.

Here is the code:

```
var comp_select = jQuery("select[class='xf-depselect-selector depselect-fragment']").get(3);

alert("some text");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   jQuery(comp_select).append(new Option(data[i]["component_name"], data[i]["component_name"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code, it sounds like a race condition. Is the code to append the items inside the success callback from the ajax call, or is it a function called after calling the ajax method? The loop through 'data' would suggest the callback but I wouldn't be able to tell for sure from that snippet

Comment: jQuery.ajax({                
    url: "the_url.php"
    success: function(data){
      var comp_select = jQuery("select[class='xf-depselect-selector depselect-fragment']").get(3);      
      alert("Ready Now");      
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      jQuery(comp_select).append(jQuery('<option>', { value : data[i]["component_name"] }).text(data[i]["component_name"]));
      }      
                },
                        complete: function() {},
                        async: false,
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });

Comment: At the point of the success callback, is the 4th select in the DOM? Is it possible to give the select you want to append an ID to make sure it is adding to the correct select? The get function is a 0 based index so it could be that it is adding to the wrong select, if you are saying it is adding to the page but not able to select the item. As an aside, you could make the append more efficient by adding all the options to an array and doing the .append once using arrayVar.join('') to append all items in one go so the DOM is only hit once

Comment: Yes it is the correct DOM element  only. its able to add the items properly but only shoiwng after writing an alert(). and, yes i tried putting all options into an array. and appending all at once to the select. but did not work. folloiwng is theat code: `var comp_select = jQuery("select[class='xf-depselect-selector depselect-fragment']").get(3);
alert("Ready Now");
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
 sellist += '<option value="'+data[i]["component_name"]+'">'+data[i]["component_name"]+'</option>';
}
jQuery(comp_select).html(sellist); `

Comment: Now i've got access to a desktop machine rather than mobile, I was able to create a mock-up of your situation. I think your problem may well be the .get(3) to get the 4th select. I changed that to be $(selector)[3] and then the options appared.I knocked up a JSFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/chb3zb47/

Comment: no use steven, still the same behaviour. and how can i put my code here in the comments box here.

Comment: to put code in the comments box wrap the code with <code> tags. There may well be another error causing the problem, which could be visible in the developer console (F12 in IE and Chrome)